# How to have category name as Legend instead of series in Highchart for Angular?

Tags: angular, highcharts, angular2-highcharts

I was trying to implement a highchart column chart in angular with multilevel drill down. Since I am not able to add multiple series to drill down in highchart for Angular, I plan to use a single series with multiple categories as my drilldown series but I am unable to show legend this way. Is there any way to do this?

I tried to use `addseriesasdrilldown()` function of highchart but it will let me add only one series to drill down. I also tried to make a single series with multiple categories but I can't show in legend this way.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Both features are not supported by default in Highcharts, but it is really easy to add them.

To add more than one series to drill down, you can use `addSingleSeriesAsDrilldown` internal method. For example:

```
chart.addSingleSeriesAsDrilldown(point, series1);
chart.addSingleSeriesAsDrilldown(point, series2);
chart.applyDrilldown();
```

Useful thread: https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=34240

---

To create something like legend per category, set `legendType: 'point'` and borrow `setVisible` method from pie series. For example:

```
Highcharts.seriesTypes.column.prototype.pointClass.prototype.setVisible = Highcharts.seriesTypes.pie.prototype.pointClass.prototype.setVisible;

Highcharts.chart('container', {
  series: [{
    ...,
    type: 'column',
    legendType: 'point'
  }]
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/wevdcgy2/

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts